# Invalid character "/" in path section spring cloud gcp binder

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to listen to one pubsub subscription via gcp binder

build.gradle

```
ext {
    set('springCloudGcpVersion', "3.4.2")
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.5")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies:${springCloudGcpVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

application yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      credentials.location: 'classpath:creds.json'
    stream:
      function:
        definition: myConsumer
      bindings:
        catalogConsumer-in-0:
          destination: projects/projectid/subscriptions/subid
          binder: pubsub
          group: muygroup
          content-type: application/json
```

Code:

```
@Bean
  public Consumer<Message<String>> myConsumer() {
    return message -> {
      log.info("Message has been received {}, {}", message.getPayload(),
          message.getHeaders().get("heh"));
    };
  }
```

error:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.pathtemplate.ValidationException: Invalid character "/" in path section "projects/projectid/subscriptions/subid"
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.encodeUrl(PathTemplate.java:1099) ~[api-common-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.instantiate(PathTemplate.java:768) ~[api-common-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.google.api.pathtemplate.PathTemplate.instantiate(PathTemplate.java:691) ~[api-common-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.google.pubsub.v1.TopicName.toString(TopicName.java:173) ~[proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-1.105.0.jar:1.105.0]
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:557) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.123.0.jar:1.123.0]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.getTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:137) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.ensureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:136) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at com.google.cloud.spring.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionConsumerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:42) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:428) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.2.6.jar:3.2.6]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

The subscription path is valid
But I am getting this exception

Comment: Does this [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033203/) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372899/) solve your problem?